# Make image resize better on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css

The title might be misleading.

Here's my code:

```
#headerimg {
background: url('http://artotek.fi/css/images/artoteklogo.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
border-bottom: solid #696969 2px ;
background-size:  200px 250px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -6px 5px 3px rgba(76, 76, 94, 0.9);
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px -6px 5px 3px rgba(76, 76, 94, 0.9);
box-shadow:         inset 0px -10px 15px 3px rgba(76, 76, 94, 0.9);
height: 300px;
}
```

This code is suppose to keep the header image in the same place, until you scroll down, when it gets hidden behind the content.

### Here's a few images:

---

[image: 16" laptop]

### 16" laptop ^

---

[image: 24" desktop]

### 24" desktop (if [this](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http://artotek.fi/m_index.html&w=1920&h=1200&a=1&s=1) site is to be trusted) ^

---

The image should always stay contained in the header when you load the page on any screen (already tried `background-size: cover;`).

Setting the position in pixels is hopeless, and with percents pretty much too.

### How could I make the image stay inside the div when the page is scrolled to top?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew24B/)

### [Live demo](http://artotek.fi/m_index.html)

Comment: How about using Media Queries.

Comment: Nah, the site is 90% responsive already, without Queries, and I'd like to keep it simple that way

Answer (score 0):

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew24B/2/)

Modify CSS:

```
#headerimg {
background: url('http://artotek.fi/css/images/artoteklogo.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 50% 50px;/* middle 50px from top -> equal to margin-top #wrapper*/
border-bottom: solid #696969 2px ;
/*background-size:  200px 250px;*/ /*removed*/
display: block;
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -6px 5px 3px rgba(76, 76, 94, 0.9);
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px -6px 5px 3px rgba(76, 76, 94, 0.9);
box-shadow:         inset 0px -10px 15px 3px rgba(76, 76, 94, 0.9);
height: 300px;
}
```

Add the following to your js:

```
var IMAGEWIDTH = 300;// WIDTH OF THE IMAGE
var IMAGEHEIGHT = 521;// WIDTH OF THE IMAGE
var headerimg = jQuery("#headerimg");
headerimg.css({"background-size":Math.round(Math.min(headerimg.height(),IMAGEHEIGHT)*0.5)+"px "+Math.round(Math.min(headerimg.width(),IMAGEWIDTH)*0.5)+"px"});
```

Comment: No, the image is suppose to hide behind the content.

Comment: My answer is for the question "How could I make the image stay inside the div when the page is scrolled to top?" Or did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: I meant it the other way, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So you want it to be like how it already is, just that now it doesn't dissapear completely? This is because your body height is not long enough. Adding more content (so you need to scroll more) will make your image completely dissapear behind the content that follow.

Comment: I've figured that out, but the when you load the page on a bigger screen, the image gets overlapped by the content, when it should be all visible in the header, before you scroll down.

Comment: So you want: image completely visible, when you scroll it should stay and disappear as content scrolls over it? Since you work with % you need to use jquery to determine width and height of the div #headerimg and then use those dimensions to place the image in the background of that div. I updated the answer.

Comment: Not working. 1st: Try to resize the fiddle 'Result' screen. 2nd: http://imgur.com/0wbCwJT

Comment: I tweaked it (see updated answer) to better align the start of the lightbulb image. `background-position` is dependent on `margin-top:` from the `#wrapper` It works perfect with me. Implement it on a demo site and give url for me to double check.

Comment: In your updated demo external css does not get applied. I cannot see the lightbulb image, can you?

Comment: So the page is just HTML? That does happen from time to time on my page... Try refreshing it a few times, and clearing cache

Comment: Yes there are also errors with your js (nicescroll is not found) and a few code issues with your `document.ready` js code. (line 33 `&gt;` needs to be `>` and line 51 you need to remove the new line after `"px`

Comment: Invalid code causes things to break, fixing it would mean it fixes everything or at least brings us one step closer to getting it right ;-)

Comment: Fixed it but it didn't affect anyhing... Whatever, going back to the original plan :D